# How to build kernel module without full kernel source tree?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I would like to build kernel module without kernel source tree. 
Instead that, I specified the kernel header directory only.

This reference link tell me it should be workable :
[build kernel module w/o source source tree](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/build-linux-kernel-module-against-installed-kernel-source-tree.html)

But some other reference links tell me should build module with full kernel source tree!

My question is :
1. Shall I build kernel module link with full kernel source tree ?
2. Is it necessary to do a full build under kernel source tree before build my single module ?

Comment: 1) You can build kernel module without full kernel source tree, only kernel headers are needed. 2) No need to build entire kernel source before building your module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Not it's not necessary. You need a header files that contains function and types declarations. You also kernel tree  with Makefiles and Kconfig **but without sources**. This kernel tree is needed by kbuild - kernel building system.
2. Absolutely not. You can build a single module without building whole kernel regardless of it's out-of-tree or in-tree module.

Comment: What are the purposes of Makefiles and Kconfig while I building module?
In the view point of GCC compiler and linker, just need headers to compile and libraries to link (I known ko is runtime link in kernel).
That's why I'm so confused !

Comment: First of all, you are building modules with `make` utility. `make` knows only Makefiles which describes dependencies between objects like "usb driver depends on driver core". GCC and linker **are invoked by make**. GCC and linker looks for header files and libraries. 

Kconfig describes kernel options - the one that you can configure with `make menuconfig`. Kconfig sets options that transforms to C macro `CONFIG_<OPTION>` like `CONFIG_SMP`.

Answer (score -1):

No to both questions. You're talking about out-of-tree (or "external") modules.

Here is a tutorial of [Building External Modules](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt).

And here is a simple sample of a Makefile.

```
obj-m += your-module.o
KDIR=/lib/modules/`uname -r`/build
default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
```